# Divide two pandas Series

Tags: pandas

trying to divide 2 series but im getting a behavior i dont understand

```
a = 14    0.27
    15    0.11
    16    0.00
    dtype: float64
```

`a.index` returns

```
Int64Index([14, 15, 16], dtype='int64')
```

and

```
b = 14    0.150286
    15    0.108026
    16    0.000000
    dtype: float64
```

`b.index` returns

```
Index([u'14', u'15', u'16'], dtype='object')
```

When i do

```
a.divide(b) or a/b
```

i get the same result

```
14   NaN
15   NaN
16   NaN
14   NaN
15   NaN
16   NaN
```

this should be pretty simple but i dont understand why is returning the series instead of returning the expected

```
   14   1.7965
   15   1.0182
   16   NaN
```

Comment: It seems there is different type of indexes, one is string and another int.

Comment: but if same indexes, you can use `a.divide(b.values)`

Comment: both series are type `float64` @jezrael

Comment: `a / b` returns the same result @bernie

Comment: And what `a.index` and `b.index` ?

Comment: I think the index are the problem b.index are strings and a.index are Ints. I guess i need to make sure both indexs are the same datatype as well as the series values

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I think there are different `dtypes` of `indexes`, so need same type - e.g. cast `object` (obviously `str`) to `int`:

```
a = pd.Series([0.27, 0.11, 0], index=['14','15','16'])
b = pd.Series([0.150286, 0.108026, 0], index=[14,15,16])
print (a)
14    0.27
15    0.11
16    0.00
dtype: float64

print (b)
14    0.150286
15    0.108026
16    0.000000
dtype: float64

print (a.index.dtype)
object
print (b.index.dtype)
int64

#cast to int
a.index = a.index.astype(int)
print (a.div(b))
14    1.796575
15    1.018273
16         NaN
dtype: float64
```

Comment: Thanks i was getting very confused since i could not understand why i was getting such results for something that looked so simple

Answer (score 1):

Switching to numpy arrays and getting back to a pandas series afterwards can also work:

```
a = pd.Series([0.27, 0.11, 0], index=['14','15','16'])
b = pd.Series([0.150286, 0.108026, 0], index=[14,15,16])

# the index to keep 
my_index = a.index()

c = a.values / b.values
c = pd.Series(c, index=my_index)
```